# IMG Silde change function stops working when having two functions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that changes the image of a container every 5 seconds and it works fine. The issue is I am trying to add 2 containers side to side then change their images simultaneously but when I run the functions for both the containers, only one of the container img starts to change the other one stays still but if I run one of the either functions its works properly and starts to change the img. How can I make both containers change their img every 5 sec. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
let index = 0;
const slides1 = document.querySelectorAll(".mainDisplay1 .slide1");

function change1() {
  if (++index >= slides1.length)
    index = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < slides1.length; i++)
    slides1[i].classList.toggle("active1", i == index);
}

const slides2 = document.querySelectorAll(".mainDisplay2 .slide2");

function change2() {
  if (++index >= slides2.length)
    index = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < slides2.length; i++)
    slides2[i].classList.toggle("active2", i == index);
}

//calling one of the 2 functions work but only one of them works when calling both


window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(change1, 5000);
};

window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(change2, 5000);
};
```

```css
.mainDisplay1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  left: 0%;
  border-radius: 2%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 3px 31px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
  box-shadow: 10px 3px 31px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
}

.mainDisplay1 img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 600px;
}

.mainDisplay2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  left: 0%;
  border-radius: 2%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 3px 31px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
  box-shadow: 10px 3px 31px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
}

.mainDisplay2 img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 600px;
  float: right;
}

.slide1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  position: absolute;
}

.active1 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  position: initial;
}

.slide2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  position: absolute;
}

.active2 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  position: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDisplay1">
  <img class="slide1 active1" src="Img1.jpg">
  <img class="slide1" src="Img2.jpg">
  <img class="slide1" src="Img3.jpg">
  <img class="slide1" src="Img4.jpg">
</div>

<div class="mainDisplay2">
  <img class="slide2 active2" src="Img5.jpg">
  <img class="slide2" src="Img6.jpg">
  <img class="slide2" src="Img7.jpg">
  <img class="slide2" src="Img8.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the node list each time you call the function and you need to separate your `index` variable from each other or you double up on the increment. Also when you add two different functions to the `window.onload` the latest will overwrite the first which means the first is now never called.

```js
let index1 = 0;
let index2 = 0;

function change1() {
  const slides1 = document.querySelectorAll(".mainDisplay1 .slide1");

  if (++index1 >= slides1.length)
    index1 = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < slides1.length; i++)
    slides1[i].classList.toggle("active1", i == index1);
}


function change2() {
  const slides2 = document.querySelectorAll(".mainDisplay2 .slide2");

  if (++index2 >= slides2.length)
    index2 = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < slides2.length; i++)
    slides2[i].classList.toggle("active2", i == index2);
}


window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(change1, 5000);
  setInterval(change2, 5000);
};
```

```css
.mainDisplay1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  left: 0%;
  border-radius: 2%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 3px 31px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
  box-shadow: 10px 3px 31px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
}

.mainDisplay1 img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 600px;
}

.mainDisplay2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  left: 0%;
  border-radius: 2%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 3px 31px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
  box-shadow: 10px 3px 31px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
}

.mainDisplay2 img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 600px;
  float: right;
}

.slide1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  position: absolute;
}

.active1 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  position: initial;
}

.slide2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  position: absolute;
}

.active2 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  position: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDisplay1">
  <img class="slide1 active1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=Img1">
  <img class="slide1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=Img2">
  <img class="slide1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=Img3">
  <img class="slide1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=Img4">
</div>

<div class="mainDisplay2">
  <img class="slide2 active2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=Img5">
  <img class="slide2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=Img6">
  <img class="slide2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=Img7">
  <img class="slide2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=Img8">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your onload functions for example like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    change1();
    change2();
  }, 5000);
}
```

You cannot call `onload` multiple times.